# Get suggested filename from org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Tags: android, httpclient, httpresponse, http-get, content-disposition

In Android, you can download a file using the `org.apache.http` classes `HttpClient`, `HttpGet` and `HttpResponse`. How can I read the suggested filename from the HTTP request?

E.g. In PHP, you would do this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blah.txt');
```

How do I get the "blah.txt" using the Apache classes in Android/Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BasicHeader header = new BasicHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=blah.txt");
HeaderElement[] helelms = header.getElements();
if (helelms.length > 0) {
    HeaderElement helem = helelms[0];
    if (helem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("attachment")) {
        NameValuePair nmv = helem.getParameterByName("filename");
        if (nmv != null) {
            System.out.println(nmv.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

---

sysout> blah.txt

Answer (score 3):

```
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

//observe all headers by this
Header[] h = response.getAllHeaders();
for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(h[i].getName() + "  " + h[i].getValue());
}

//choose one header by giving it's name
Header header = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition");
String s = header.getValue()
```